# lossing text with meta viewport

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, responsive

I'm making my first blog and I'm trying to make it responsive, I use the meta viewport but when I test it with Google Chrome in different size windows, the text i wrote disappears.
here's some of my code I wrote in css and html showing my problem:

```css
.hero{
    background-color: firebrick;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/MSI/Documents/programacion/html_y_css/estilos_test.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scape=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <article>
                <h1> ¿quien soy?</h1>
                    <p> araragi koyomi: estudiante de bioingeniería . amante de la naturaleza; me gustan
                        las plantas y los animales en general, amo las matemáticas, me siento cómodo en lugares silenciosos y disfruto de ver anime,
                        salir con amigos, el queso, el vino y el chocolate, me encanta la programación y planeo enfocar mi carrera en programación 
                        tanto como pueda.
            </article>
            <figure>
                <img class="image-item" src="C:\Users\MSI\Documents\programacion\html_y_css\imagenes\viajes\yo_laguna.jpg" alt="no se encuentra una imagen" width="400px">
                <small> Figura: viaje a la laguna del otún</small>
            </figure>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to solve it with the property max-width but the content shown in the window also include the body, does someone know how to resolve this problem? Thank you. Stackoverflow does not allow me to upload images.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a definite width. Your width is set to 1000px, which is fixed, meaning no matter what the device's with is, the element will only span 1000px. To fix this, you can either use percentages, which conforms an element to a certain width relative to its parent element -- or by using viewer width, which defines the element's width relative to the user's screen, or viewport. Here is how to do it both ways:

Percentage:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Viewer Width:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.